# Mobile Automation Signature Issue

Tags: javascript, android

Trying to automate android mobile, I am facing issue to automate the signature. there are no locators for that field. so please suggest me how to handle signature

[image]

Comment: Hi Rohit I didn't understand your question. What type of automation and what are locators

Comment: hi @killer  i am trying to automate signature pad where i need to put signature under mobile automation , but when i am trying to inspect the signature pad , i am not getting any locators for that. please find attached image which i have been attached during creation of issue , please do need full help

Comment: Ok i really don't understand your question as it is mixed with javascript and automation. I would advice you to add more/specific details so that other audience can understand it clearly. As Android TAG is vast. Also please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get maximum help from community

Answer (score 0):

You can use Signature pad library, its working perfect without any trouble...
[https://github.com/gcacace/android-signaturepad[1](https://github.com/gcacace/android-signaturepad)

Comment: I hope he doesn't mean that. As the question is tag with javascript and jargons like automation and loaders. Can you explain that

Comment: TQ @Hitesh Kushwah i will try and get back to you

Comment: HI @Hitesh KUshwah i am trying to automate the signature pad , but you suggested me to developed , please help me out in MObile  AUtomation area.